# How to prevent tags replacement?

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to parse html code as java input stream. I have this html code in stream:

```
<p contenteditable=true><ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li></ul></p>
```

and after calling `Jsoup.parse(stream)` I have as result

```
<p contenteditable=true></p><ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li></ul>
```

How to prevent code modifying? I don't need to change html code. How to fix this? why it replaces `<p>` tag?

Comment: `parse` returns a `Document`. So explain what you do to get back to a string as that might be the culpret. Perhaps provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @weston, I see it in debugger. So, I provide to you what I give to this method and result - what is exactly in Document. And html is different

Comment: Sure, make the smallest example that demonstrates the problem. Ideally it should be so that someone can copy and see it for them selves and investigate. It should help track down basic errors like the one you posted before the update too.

Comment: But it doesn't seem necessary now as you have a correct answer.

Comment: @weston, I guess that problem is in invalid html code. It's not normal that p tag contains `<li>` elements inside. And library normalize document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'ul' elements are not legally allowed inside 'p' elements, so probably Jsoup normalize it.
Maybe `Document xmlDoc = Jsoup.parse(html, baseUri, Parser.xmlParser());` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Well you gave Jsoup invalid xHTML but valid HTML 4 and 5 assuming you didn't mean to close the p tag. Also p tags cannot contain list tags so if you did mean to close the p tag it's invalid for almost all HTML.

I guess Jsoup tries to normalize to xHTML and there are not many parsers that don't. The only parser that I know that preserves the nodes exactly is Jericho.