# Turn off automatic close tag in jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to turn off automatic generation of close tags and I referred to this link

[How to turn off automatic generation of close tags </tagName> in Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040626/how-to-turn-off-automatic-generation-of-close-tags-tagname-in-jsoup)

```
 String html="<A HREF=\"#Item1\">\n"
                + "<p style=\"font-family:times;margin-top:12pt;margin-left:0pt;\">\n"
                + "<FONT SIZE=2>Item&nbsp;1.</FONT>\n"
                + "</A>";
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html,"",Parser.xmlParser());
```

But when I try I am not getting any output and I think it is going into a inifinte loop or something.

This is the code with which I am trying: ( no output and hanging)

```
String html = "<table>"
                + "<tr align='top'>"
                + "<th><font>Link</th>"
                + "</tr>"
                + "</table>";

        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html,"",Parser.xmlParser());
        System.out.println(document.toString());
```

Can someone tell me what the error is?
What I need is some sort of an ouput saying that the end tag is missing.

---

EDIT - Sorry there was some problem with my eclipse.Anyway now there is no infinite loop but my output is as follows

```
String html = "<table>"
                + "<tr align='top'>"
                + "<th><font>Link</th>"
                + "</tr>"
                + "</table>";

        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html,"",Parser.xmlParser());

          System.out.println("UNPARSED = \n"+html + "\n---------------");
        System.out.println("parsed:" + document.toString());
```

Output

```
UNPARSED = 
<table><tr align='top'><th><font>Link</th></tr></table>
---------------
parsed:<table>
 <tr align="top">
  <th><font>Link</font></th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I dont want the `</font>` to be added.

---

Edit -

I fixed it by checking using Regular expressions before parsing by Jsoup.

Answer (score 1):

@Abi I don't think the example can remove `close tag`, even if you use the `xmlParser` to parse your html, `Jsoup` still will add `close tag` to the unclosed tag. because for `xml` or `html` node must have open tag with closed tag. your example has proved this.

I think you can use `regexp` to do this.

Comment: I want to do a match between all the opening and closing tags and see if its properly matched.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: In my example <font> does not have a closing tag. I want that to be pointed out.

Comment: @Abi You need a html validator, I didn't find an Jsoup api can output the verbose info or maybe you can modify `Jsoup` to do this thing.

Comment: @Abi I have found [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) can `getParseErrors` and `getParseWarnings`: http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/w3c/tidy/Tidy.html#getParseErrors()

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am supposed to use Jsoup. I resolved the error by checking the tags using Regular expressions before Parsing by jsoup.